# Unable to setup *ad hoc* on WiFi modules that have multiple Radio Interfaces - MT7915

Tags: networking, ifconfig, ad-hoc-network

Some background: We have an *ad hoc* network running on 5GHz already. We are looking for new WiFi modules that support *ad hoc* on 5GHz. Through suggestions we found a website called AsiaRF that sells WiFi modules and they claim that they support 5GHz *ad hoc*.

I bought several modules from them. They have Single and Multi Radio channel modules. The 2 single channel versions that I had tried have worked as expected and I was able to connect to the 5GHz network that already exists. All of these are MediaTek based.

I bought several ones that have multiple radio interfaces:

- AW7915-NPD
- AW7915-NP1
- AW7615-NP1
- AW7916-NPD

However, I'm a little confused because the process isn't the same.

The AW7915-NPD is supposed to have both 2.4 and 5GHz on each interface. Using it as a client I can see 2.4GHz on one radio and 5GHz on the other radio only. When setting up the *ad hoc* on the 5GHz version, I can connect to the *ad hoc* network with the correct BSSID, but can't ping or connect to the other nodes.

For the AW7915-NP1 I can only see one radio interface on `ifconfig`, even though this version's description says it's supposed to be able to select the required frequency on each of the radio interfaces.

Maybe I'm confused on how to use these or I'm misunderstanding something. If someone has any knowledge I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You didn't mention what OS you're using. On Linux most of the time you can get their capabilities and possible uses using `iw phy0 info` (replace phy0 with the adequate phy name). Look under `valid interface combinations` and compare what is available from the different cards.